# How to display % sign and th at the end of numeric value on graph in crystal report 2013

Tags: crystal-reports

I have been using crystal report 2013. On the graph we have been using the numeric value. I would like to display % sign and th at the end of number. eg 5% or 4th etc..

[I would like to put % and th sign on the bar graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHa9z.png) labels are value directly coming from the table and its not static. I haven't used any formula to display number on graph. I am using crystal report 13 version.

Answer (score 0):

Create Text object and insert the symbol % inside it then add the parameter field next to it, same you can do for (th).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the "data labels", right click the chart and select "chart options", then "general", tab "data labels", check "show data labels". Then go to tab "numbers" and set "category" = "percent".

Maybe your data will be multiplied by 100. Then, you should create a formula to divide the number by 100 and use the formula instead of using directly the field.

Another possibility: I do not know if applies to the chart, but in a field, you can right click it, "format object", tab "number", click "customize...", tab "currency symbol", "enable currency symbol", change "position" to the rigth, change the "currency symbol" to "%" or " %".